# Boostrap Confidence Intervals For 3 Distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, python, bootstrap

I am having 3 distributions (A/B/C) and I would like to check if there is any statistical significance difference in their means. The goal is to choose the one with the higher mean if there is a statistical significant difference.

I already did that for 2 distributions (A/B) by computing the 95% Confidence Interval of their mean difference using Bootraping method. If the CI interval would have 0 inside it I will conclude that the distributions are the same, otherwise I will reject the null hypothesis.

My question is, how can I do the same in the case of 3 distributions or more?

Should I compute their mean difference paiwise ?

Comment: If you have the distributions, you can calculate the means and simply compare them. There's no need to invoke statistical tests because there's no uncertainty. Or did you mean that you actually have *samples* from 3 distributions, but the distributions themselves are unknown? In which case you'd have to *estimate* the mean from the samples, and statistical tests would be needed

Comment: Yes, I actually have the samples. Those of are the results for an A/B/C test on a website.